# SOAPUI: Convert string to XML

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

i´m new in SOAPUI and i have two projects. The first one is a generic and is responsible for running the second  and get the response. 
I already got there, but for that i put the response in to a property.

Project 2 :

```
def responseXML = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("SOAP#Response").getXml()
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("RESPONSE", responseXML );
```

In the project 1 i can acess to the response and i can printed.

```
def response = project.getPropertyValue('RESPONSE')
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('RESPONSE', response)
```

But when i trie acess to the XML alays say that is null or not aplicable to a String.

I have tried:

```
 - def holder = new XmlHolder( RESPONSE.responseContentAsXml )
 - def list = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
 - def list = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
```

Any one can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: how you can print xml from second project? could you also print `.getClass()` of your xml variable. what is exact exception gives `new XmlParser().parseText(...)` of `new XmlSlurper().parseText(...)` ?

Comment: It looks a bit strange to me, in the second line of code shown above you are setting project property("RESPONSE") of Project 2, but you are getting project property("RESPONSE") for response in Project 1? If so these are different properties.

Comment: PS: You can check property value in SoapUI, unless you override/delete it, can you check it?

Comment: The best practise is that each and every test case is independent. Here you are linking multiple project which is not the right way. You need to consider redesign of your tests.

Comment: Thank you for everything, I've already discover the answer !!

def resp = new XmlParser(false, true, true)
def txt = resp.parseText(RESPONSE)

log.info 'NAME: ' + txt.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'name' }*.text()[0]